# How can I give give out these names randomly?

Tags: java, eclipse

My task is:
Write a method that takes an array of names – the array can be any length so from one
name to a million names. The method should randomly return a single name as the
winner.
**These are my inputs/outputs**

Input: An array of names [Suzy, Tim, Toyin,
Heather, Gail, Melanie]
Output: One of the names from the list Toyin

My code so far is:

```
public String andTheWinnerIs(String[] name) {
    String[] names = {"Bob", "Jill", "Tom", "Brandon"};
    int index = (Math.random() * names.length);
    String namefinal = names[index];
    return namefinal;
}
```

Can anybody help me with that? It just gives me errors :(

I am working with Java Eclipse

Comment: A good way to understand what's going wrong is to use the debugger. Look up how to use the debugger in Eclipse

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to explain better what is the error you receive. Also Eclipse is an IDE for Java Developers. Your code is written in Java, has nothing to do with Eclipse, or any other IDE or editor

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt has a String array as an input and it does nothing with that array. You should not create the array inside that method.

Check this code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Main m = new Main();
        String[] names = {"Bob", "Jill", "Tom", "Brandon"};
        System.out.println("The winner is: " + m.andTheWinnerIs(names));
    }

    public String andTheWinnerIs(String[] name) {
        int index = (int) (Math.random() * name.length);
        return name[index];
    }
```

As you see I kept only the random code block of your code inside `andTheWinnerIs` method. In the main method you should first create the Main class object so you can call the non-static method `andTheWinnerIs`. Alternatively you can make that method static: `public static String andTheWinnerIs(String[] name)`

Happy Coding..

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Random().nextInt()` from java.util package instead of **Math.random() which internally calls Random.nextDouble()**. So that we avoid typecasting from double to int.

```
public String andTheWinnerIs(String[] name) {
    String[] names = {"Bob", "Jill", "Tom", "Brandon"};
    int index = new Random().nextInt(names.length);
    String namefinal = names[index];
    return namefinal;
}
```

Comment: I just finished it myself now doing: 


public String andTheWinnerIs(String[] names) {
  String random = (names[new Random().nextInt(names.length)]);
  return random;

Comment: Ah ok !! feel free to update your answer or accept my answer